# Where to post product-management-related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On what Stack Exchange site can I post questions related to product management? (pricing, acquiring users, increasing conversions, etc.)

I noticed there [was an Area 51 proposal for that](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103542/business-analysis-and-product-management), but is was removed.  Any other sites on SE?

Comment: Assuming *some* relationship with the SOFU audience, I guess an answer, if any, might better be added to [Where can I ask questions that aren't programming questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)

Answer (score 2):

The closest site is the [Startup](http://startups.stackexchange.com) site. I think the field deserves its own as product management in startups has different goals in mature enterprises.

You can follow the draft [product management stack exchange site on area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103542/business-analysis-and-product-management) to help make it official.